# How taking the wrapper width for my div?

Tags: css

I have next style for the web page:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdJMz.png

I have a div in the "What I Want" zone which is bordered by the left sidebar and right sidebar.

How do I make the div to take width of the wrapper and overlap sidebar.

Comment: Post relative code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

z-index should work. However, do you want `"What I Want"` to be fixed? otherwise, You would have to use `Margin-top: "insert height of "What I Want"px;` to overlap the sidebar. Your best option would be to make each `sidebar + content` the same height. And have `"what I want"` to be the `width: 100%;`

However, you dont give us much to go with, do you have any relevant code?